# Identify action browser close, referesh, tab close when event is beforeunload

Tags: javascript, html

Hi Identify action when user unloads page,

[image]

Because I thought that when user `clicks out of document then mouse position is 0` and we can tell that user clicked on close button "beforeUnload" is called.

So my problem is to identify 4 things,

- when user clicks on close button of browser (something like mouse position negetive)
- when user clicks on close button of tab
- when user clicks on close button refresh button
- uses F5 to refresh page.

When any of this action is performed "BeforeUnload" is called.

Here is my code,

```html
<html>
     <head>
         <title>Page Title</title>
             <script>

                 var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
 
                 document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
                 mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX; 
                 mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY 
                 }, false);
  
                 if (window.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
              window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
           var confirmationMessage = "Hi";
           alert(mouse.x + ' : ' + mouse.y);     
          return confirmationMessage;                            
           });
                }
                else {
                 if (window.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
              window.attachEvent("beforeunload", function (e) {
              var confirmationMessage = "Hi";
           alert(mouse.x + ' : ' + mouse.y);
        return confirmationMessage;                            
           });

                 }
                }
        </script>
        </head>

     <body>
          <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
          <p id = "myAns">This is a paragraph.</p>
     </body>

</html>
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: What if a user clicks the back button on their mouse? The mouse position at that point could be anywhere on the screen.

Comment: There is no real way to do it.

Comment: @epascarello Are u saying that we can't diff this actions ?

Comment: @NaimishViradia Ye, that is what epascarello is saying. You can detect the unload event, but you won't be able to differentiate how the unload event was called (back button, close button, reload, etc etc)

Comment: What happens when the user navigates with right click of a mouse? What happens when they use programmed keys on their keyboard or mouse? What happens when they click a bookmark? What happens when they use keyboard navigation? It is impossible to get all the actions. Not all browsers give negative numbers. Users can get to the toolbar without moving over the webpage with their mouse. You are better off detecting things you control. Set a flag when the user clicks a link, submits a form, page navigates with code, etc. Use that flag to determine if they are leaving.

Comment: @epascarello Got it. so can we detect event come from outside the document ? This all events are not generated from documents ya.